# How do I inject a dependency into an interface delegate in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, delegates, composition

I'm trying to figure out how to inject a dependency into an interface delegate in Kotlin. I have a class:

```
class MyThingie {}
```

And I want to add a field `created_time` to this class that might also be added to other classes. So I can create an interface and an instance implementation of this interface, and then add that delegation into the class definition:

```
interface ThingieWithCreatedTS {
    val created_ts: Long
}

object ThingieCreatedAtNow : ThingieWithCreatedTS {
    override val created_ts: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
}

class MyThingie : ThingieWithCreatedTS by ThingieCreatedAtNow {}
```

This is great. Now I can call `created_ts` on any instance of `MyThingie` and get the timestamp it was created. However, this is now hard to test.

I don't really want to be trying to mock `System`, and I understand the correct pattern for this is to inject some sort of Clock instance into whatever needs to know the current time. That way, I can provide a RealClock in the code, and under test I can provide a FakeClock (that I can control the output from).

It's not clear how I can do this on this pattern. How can I pass an implementation instance into a delegate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just use constructor dependency injection?

```
class MyThingie(
    dep: ThingieWithCreatedTS = ThingieCreatedAtNow
) : ThingieWithCreatedTS by dep {}
```

Now you can provide fake `ThingieWithCreatedTS` dependency in tests

Comment: Amazing. I had no idea that you could take the delegate implementation from a constructor field. Thanks!

Comment: How to achieve the same when dealing with an Activity? We cannot constructor inject Activities.